# Does a bounty from someone other than the asker get awarded to the accepted answer?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

If I have not misunderstood the bounty mechanism, when a user starts a bounty on his question, the bounty could be awarded to whichever response he wants, and not just the accepted answer. Am I wrong? If somebody else starts a bounty on my question, and I accept an answer, will the bounty be awarded to the accepted answer, or can I not interfere in how the bounty will be awarded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't decide who gets the bounty - not directly.

If the person offering the bounty awards it manually, there is nothing you can do.

If they do not, and the bounty timeout has passed, you could influence who will get the bounty, but not 100%. Upvoting and accepting an answer will help make that answer go up the list of candidates.